# Excel Macro Complex Question on Search Bar Function

Tags: excel, vba, search-box

[My specific Excel file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ahxqhc08WSfqiW3vgjuvNVFtOIBJ?e=fgoc9q)

Hello, I have all the correct buttons and set up for what I believe to make my excel sheet searchable. I think there is an error in my code on the VBA on the selector values such as my range. Although I have range A6 to Y1000 selected, and my search box is C3, shouldn't this run?

The set up says my radio buttons needed to be named the exact same as the column name, thus the weird names. I would do a search bar with no radio buttons at all, just search for anything matching on the sheet but that seemed too advanced.

Does anyone know what specifically in my code is incorrect to run on a set up spreadsheet like so?
[image]

```vb
    Sub SearchBox()
    'PURPOSE: Filter Data on User-Determined Column & Text
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

    Dim myButton As OptionButton
    Dim MyVal As Long
    Dim ButtonName As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim myField As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim mySearch As Variant
      
    'Load Sheet into A Variable
      Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
      On Error Resume Next
        sht.ShowAllData
      On Error GoTo 0
      
    'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
      Set DataRange = sht.Range("A6:Y1000") 'Cell Range
      'Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Sheet1").Range 'Table

    'Retrieve User's Search Input
      mySearch = sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
      'mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
      'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input

    'Loop Through Option Buttons
      For Each myButton In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
          If myButton.Value = 1 Then
            ButtonName = myButton.Text
            Exit For
          End If
      Next myButton
      
    'Determine Filter Field
      On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
        myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
      On Error GoTo 0
      
    'Filter Data
      DataRange.AutoFilter _
        Field:=myField, _
        Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch & "*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
      
    'Clear Search Field
      sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
      'sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
      'sht.Range("A6").Value = "" 'Cell Input

    Exit Sub

    'ERROR HANDLERS
    HeadingNotFound:
      MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
        vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"
        
    End Sub
```

I either have nothing happen, or get an error code like this one:
[image]

[A reference on where I got most of the VBA code from](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/11/3/filtering-search-box)

Comment: The error is probably because the active sheet doesn't have the shape "UserSearch", though hard to tell without the error number and description. Having `xlAnd` on a single criteria seems off and may be why it isn't returning anything when it doesn't error out.

Comment: Using `CTRL+F` would have saved you a lot of time.

Comment: @Warcupine , that ended up being an issue as well, Runtime error 1004

Answer (score 0):

You Need to remplace you text field by a ActiveX Textbox

[image]

And access if like this:

```
Sheets("Feuil1").TextBox1.Text = ""
```

You need to replace you searching line too:

```
mySearch = Sheets("Feuil1").TextBox1.Text
```

I've updated your code, just DON'T FORGET to update your sheetname

```
Sub SearchBox()
    'PURPOSE: Filter Data on User-Determined Column & Text
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

    Dim myButton As OptionButton
    Dim MyVal As Long
    Dim ButtonName As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim myField As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim mySearch As Variant
      
    'Load Sheet into A Variable
      Set sht = ActiveSheet

    'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
      On Error Resume Next
        sht.ShowAllData
      On Error GoTo 0
      
    'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
      Set DataRange = sht.Range("A6:Y1000") 'Cell Range
      'Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Sheet1").Range 'Table

    'Retrieve User's Search Input
      mySearch = Sheets("Feuil1").TextBox1.Text 'Control Form
      'mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
      'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input

    'Loop Through Option Buttons
      For Each myButton In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
          If myButton.Value = 1 Then
            ButtonName = myButton.Text
            Exit For
          End If
      Next myButton
      
    'Determine Filter Field
      On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
        myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
      On Error GoTo 0
      
    'Filter Data
      DataRange.AutoFilter _
        Field:=myField, _
        Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch & "*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
      
    'Clear Search Field
      Sheets("Feuil1").TextBox1.Text = "" 'Control Form
      'sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
      'sht.Range("A6").Value = "" 'Cell Input

    Exit Sub

    'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
      MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
        vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"
        
End Sub
```